# Change Jquery variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, dom

I need to put a Javascript variable into php variable, I dont know how to do that. Possible answers are appreciatable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#number_of_inwards,#number_of_outwards').each(function(){

              var product_name,total_stock;

              $('#product_name').change(function(){

                product_id = $('#product_name').val();    

              });

              var hello = "13";
              <?php $d = '<script>hello</script>' ?>
              total_stock = <?php echo $st[$d]; ?>;
              console.log(total_stock);

              $(this).focusout(function(){
                var inward = parseInt($('#number_of_inwards').val());
                var outward = parseInt($('#number_of_outwards').val());
                $('#overall_stock').val(parseInt(inward+outward));
                console.log("Inside the Loop"+ inward + outward);
              })          

            })                    

          });

    </script>
```

Here from the code.I added dummy variable

> hello="13"

And tried to get it into php variable but It won't work, It returns empty value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can achieve this  using `AJAX`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp To explain it a little bit, php runs on the serverside, your JS code runs on the client side so you need an way to comunicate between them. This is possible via Ajax

Comment: Thanks mate...But Is there any possiblities do it with using Jquery??

Comment: @silambarasanR.D No, cause of what I explained to you. JS is sperated from php. JS and Jquery just run at your users pc. Php just on the server.  But you can use AJAX with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Once a web page is loaded, the client can turn off the internet connection; javascript will keep working.  Javascript lives embedded in the webbrowser of the client.  So obviously the server cannot just see what the client does on his/her pc.  Ajax is technique that allows javascript to surf the internet, so it can send forms, and receive webpages as answer.  That's how you can transmit data